# CSS Form style make border fade on click

Tags: css

whats the best CSS to use to make a text input border fade in/out when its clicked on or off?

i have this CSS at the moment that shows the border, but i want a way to make it fade in/out rather than just appear

```
.cbp-mc-form input,
.cbp-mc-form textarea {
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    border:1px solid #f36f25;
}
```

Comment: Google `jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut`

Answer (score 3):

```css
input {
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
    transition: all .3s linear;
    outline: 0;
}

input:focus {
    border: 3px solid #f36f25;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s8phX/)

Comment: Note: Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the transition property. Ref. http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp (still plus 1 though :))

Comment: Also, might want to add `-webkit-transition: width 3s; /* Safari */`